# question about duplicate management and record types

Tags: duplicate-management

I'm trying around with the new duplicate management functionality and am coming across something that seems counter-intuitive. We have two record types for contact and I set up a duplicate rule so that it only runs when we're creating/editing contacts for "Record Type 1". Here's the issue:

Although the duplicate rules don't run when creating/editing a contact from "Record Type 2", I can't stop the system from looking at "Record Type 2" contacts when creating "Record Type 1" contacts. If someone is creating a contact of "Record Type 1", it also searches for duplicates from within "Record Type 2".

Any one has any suggestion here?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is enhanced with spring 15 release so also go throgh those changes and I think there is something  wrong in  your ''duplicate rules'' follow this link for further help 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCFvif4Iipo